# JSON error with \r\n in C# string

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm working with php on the backend and C# on client side.
So when I receive multiline message from server in JSON I do this:

```
dynamic answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultHttpPost);
string body = answer.body;
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Symbol of new line is in constant

Because of this I can't use multilines messages.

I tried like this and it didn't work either

```
resultHttpPost = resultHttpPost.Replace("\\n", "\n").Replace("\\r", "\r").Replace("\\t", "\t");
  project.Variables["var_dump"].Value = resultHttpPost;
dynamic answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultHttpPost);
```

So how do I make it work?

Example for JSON:

```
{"status":"response_ok","message":{"body":"Hi test,\r\n\r\ntesting it, lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum.\r\n\r\nSignature","id":1015,"id_thread":741},"id_thread":741}
```

Comment: Show exaple `resultHttpPost` value.

Comment: {"status":"response_ok","message":{"body":"Hi test,\r\n\r\ntesting it, lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum.\r\n\r\nSignature","id":1015,"id_thread":741},"id_thread":741}

Comment: @Nelex why are you trying to replace newlines *at all*? C#, Json.NET and Json itself can handle newlines just fine. The code you posted also doesn't make much sense - where did you find `\\r` ? Are you confused by the debugger's representation of newlines perhaps? Have you tried deserializing the raw string?

Comment: BTW that's a compilation error, it has nothing to do with JSON. Post the actual line that generates the error. In any case, the error says that your string *literal*  (ie the string you typed in your code by hand) contains invalid escape characters and makes the compiler think that the remaining line is part of the string. Visual Studio's syntax coloring most likely shows the rest of the line as a string as well

Comment: it looks like problem with environment, because in Visual Studio it works fine

Answer (score 4):

I notice you're using this with ASP.NET.

It is most likely because you are actually serializing it **twice**. In my case, I was calling Json.NET's serialize method and then the resulting string was being returned from a Web API controller and that itself was serializing the JSON string (ASP.NET Web API internally uses Json.NET) and serializing JSON into JSON results in the `\r\n` appearing everywhere.

Comment: No i'm 100% sure it's serialized only once, I just checked it again.

Answer (score 1):

Example code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Message
{
    public string body { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int id_thread { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
    public int id_thread { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        string j = "{\"status\":\"response_ok\",\"message\":{\"body\":\"Hi test,\r\n\r\ntesting it, lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum.\r\n\r\nSignature\",\"id\":1015,\"id_thread\":741},\"id_thread\":741} ";

        RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(j);

        Console.WriteLine(ro.message.body);
    }

}
```

Result:

> Hi test,
>
> testing it, lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum.
>
> Signature

Is exaple json problematic json?

Comment: In other words, you can't reproduce the problem ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, this string should deserialize without problems.

Comment: Most likely the OP confused the escaped newlines for actual characters and tried to replace what wasn't there